# How can I store a rethinkdb geometry point with feathersjs?

Tags: geospatial, rethinkdb, feathersjs, feathers-hook

I'm using **feathersjs** with **feathers-rethinkdb** and I'm trying to store a point in the database with the create method of my service.  I have created this hook to transform a json in to a rethinkdb point :

```
const transformCoords = hook => {
  const {r}  = hook.service.options;
  const {latitude, longitude} = hook.data.coords;
  hook.data.coords = r.point(parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude));
};
```

but when I do a POST request for creating a point and that hook is being executed my backend returns this error:

```
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "`toJSON` takes 0 argument, 1 provided after:\nr.point(0, 0)",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {},
    "errors": {}
}
```

If I check the database, that point is being created ok as a **rethinkdb** point and I can do geospatial queries, so everything seems to be ok, but I want to stop sending that message error, and also I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace? Could it be that the returned `r.point` can not be serialized properly?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the issue. Once the point is stored in the database, feathers tries to serialize it but It fails. I don't know how I can store a point in the database and serialize it so it can be returned by the backend

Comment: You could normalize it back into an object manually in an `after` hook.

Comment: @Daff can you give me an example of how to do it? I just have started with feathers and I'm a still being a newbie

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html and how you can change `hook.result` before it is being serialized to JSON.